# Rails is deleting the question mark for google tracking from MailChimp clicks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, google-analytics, url-routing, mailchimp

When I send email for "sign up" with Mail Chimp, the url in the email looks like this:

```
http://sample.com/?utm_source=blahblahblah
```

However, when I click the link, a page opens in a new browser, I see the "?" disappear then I get:

```
http://sample.com/utm_source=
```

This, causes a 404 because I don't have a utm_source route in my db...

however, if I copy and paste the first url, i don't get this behavior...

I have only these three lines in my routes.rb:

```
  root :to => "home#index"
  match '/thanks' => "home#thanks"
  match '/subs' => "subs#index"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it it is because I had listed my url as "www.example.com" which redirects to "example.com" ... somehow, the redirect messes things up, all I had to do was correct url of the button to "example.com"

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `?utm` part as a string in your URL options.